# How to initialize WebGL2 Context with OffscreenCanvas in Webassembly with emscripten

Tags: javascript, webassembly, emscripten

I'm going to do some work in a web worker so that I can not have a canvas element on the DOM tree. However, `emscripten_webgl_create_context` api requires an id attached to a canvas in the DOM tree. I know I can create a canvas object by `document.createElement('canvas')` then transfer this canvas to offscreen. But still, how can I pass this offscreen canvas context to wasm?

In a nutshell, how can I create a `WebGL2RenderingContext` of `OffScreenCanvas` with emscripten in a worker thread?

Comment: I also face the same difficulties if you have something please let me know

Comment: No, it's not possible. I tried everything I could think of. Using `Module` variable or using `asm`, or pass a virtual ID. None of them worked. It seems that the `emscripten_webgl_create_context` requires to be called in the main thread. I finally do it in the main thread. @DolevDublon

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution, but it requires digging into the internals of emscripten-generated code:

```
EM_JS( intptr_t, createOffscreenContext, ( int width, int height ), {
   const offscreenCanvas = new OffscreenCanvas( width, height );
   const contextAttributes = {
      majorVersion: 2,
      minorVersion: 0,
      explicitSwapControl: false,
      proxyContextToMainThread: false,
   };
   const contextHandle = GL.createContext( offscreenCanvas, contextAttributes );
   return contextHandle;
} );
```

I came up with this after I dug into the Emscripten-generated js file and saw that `emscripten_webgl_create_context()` eventually just calls down into `GL.createContext()`.